# How do I turn a string into numbers for easier comparing

Tags: python-3.x

I have a code that generates a list now I need to compare the elements of this list however I cannot simply use these "> & <" as they are strings and sometimes are made up of numerical and non-numerical combos.

This code generates a list:

```
value = ['A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K']
suit = ['C', 'D', 'H', 'S']
deck = [(v+'-'+s) for s in suits for v in value]
```

here is the list

```
['A-C', '2-C', '3-C', '4-C', '5-C', '6-C', '7-C', '8-C', '9-C', '10-C', 'J-C', 'Q-C', 'K-C', 'A-D', '2-D', '3-D', '4-D', '5-D', '6-D', '7-D', '8-D', '9-D', '10-D', 'J-D', 'Q-D', 'K-D', 'A-H', '2-H', '3-H', '4-H', '5-H', '6-H', '7-H', '8-H', '9-H', '10-H', 'J-H', 'Q-H', 'K-H', 'A-S', '2-S', '3-S', '4-S', '5-S', '6-S', '7-S', '8-S', '9-S', '10-S', 'J-S', 'Q-S', 'K-S']
```

how can I properly code this?
this code basically says that if the values of the cards are different then whoever has the the higher ranking card wins. but of course this only applies to card pairs that has a number for a value how do I cater for the values 'A, J, Q, K,'

```
if deck[0] != deck[1]
   if deck[0][0] or deck[2][0] > deck[1][0] or deck[3][0]:
      print("P1 wins")
   else:
      print("P2 wins")
```

refer here for the ranking

```
Ranking of suits from lowest to highest is Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades
Ranking of values from lowest to highest is 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, J, Q, K, A
There are no jokers.
```

Comment: this is when you put down your ideas and learn about dicts, classes, string formatting etc...

Comment: i still don't know how to. index() isn't helping

Comment: you can start by having your cards be represented by more than just a string, a tuple, a dict, a class w/e you feel is right